# Parse.com filtering Push Notification as "multi server"

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, multiserver

first I apologize for my poor English. I'm just approaching to `Parse.com` and I'm developing a "multi-server" application that allows me to send notifications filtered by "server".

I tried two solutions but both have some issue all connected to the fact that when i start my Application i don't know which "server" the user will choose.

**Idea 1 - Real Multi Server**

1. I create manually n `Parse.com` servers, totally separated each other
2. I store all my servers keys in objects like `[Name, AppID, clientKey]`
3. My application lists the name attribute
4. The user choose his server
5. I start new `Activity` in which `onCreate()` I initialize Parse like:

   ```
   String appID = getAppID();
   String cKey = getKey();
   Parse.initialize(this, appID, cKey);
   ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
   ```
6. (If he want to change server i simply clean my App data and re-initialize Parse with the new keys)
7. Everything works fine until I try to send a Push Notification when the the app is closed (not active and not in background) when I have a `NullPointerException` due to initialization of Parse not yet called.

**Idea 2 - Simulated Multi Server**

1. I create manually ONE `Parse.com` server
2. All tables have a new Column like (just as example) `uniqueIdServer`
3. I initialize Parse in Application like:

   ```
   public class MyApplication extends Application {
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       Parse.initialize(this, "ThisTimeIHaveJustOneAppIDIt'sEasy", "SameHere");
       ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
       super.onCreate();
   }}
   ```
4. I display my old list but this time is just [name, uniqueID]
5. The user choose his "server"
6. Now i can easy filter my data with my new column and i have no problem when my app is closed because Parse will call his initializer by his own
7. But i don't know how i can filter Push Notification just for some `uniqueId`
8. I tried using channels and than sending Push only at that channel:

   ```
       List<String> channels = new ArrayList<>();
   channels.add(getUniqueID());
   ParseInstallation install = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
   install.put("channels", channels);
   install.saveEventually();
   ```
9. But is always the same, i dont know at "Application time" what my user will choose so my `getUniqueID()` will bind `"null"` or similar and even worse i don't know how can i change channel (atm i can only if i uninstall my app)

Really thanks at all, any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using your **idea 2**, installations can be given custom attributes and queried exactly as any other objects.  Moreover, pushes can be made with an installation query.  See ["advanced targeting" in the docs](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#push-notifications-using-advanced-targeting).

Minimally, you can say something like this:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.equalTo('uniqueIdServer', 'serverId123');

var data = { alert: "Ciao users of serverId123!" }

Parse.Push.send({ where: query, data: data }).then(function() {
    // this code runs after the push has been sent to APN
}, function(error) {
    // this code runs in case of an error
});
```